# Not able to access ipython notebook using public dns of ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run ipython notebook on AWS. It is running fine on the ec2 instance. But I am not able to access it through the browser. I have set the inbound rules for https correctly.

Comment: This is how I am trying to access the notebook via browser https://your-Instance's-public-DNS:8888

Comment: you said you have "inbound rules for https", but is port 8888 open?

Comment: Hi, the issue is resolved now. Yes, the port was open but it still wasn't working. There was some problem in the certificate that I had generated. I regenerated the certificate and it worked.